# Javascript Fetch and Map not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fetch a multiple page api and place the json within an array.  I've set it up so it does the required number of fetches and is setting up the correct number of promises.  I am getting 50+ different responses.  However, when I try to map each of those responses, it only pulls the first set of data and pushes that repetitively to the array.  What am I not doing correctly?

```
var data;
    fetch(URL_ARTISTS3,{
        method:'GET'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        data =json;
        const apiPromises = [];
        var pagesRequired = Math.ceil(json.setlists["@total"] / json.setlists["@itemsPerPage"]);

        for (let i=pagesRequired; i>0;i--) {
            var fetchurl = URL_ARTISTS3 + '?page = ' + i;
            apiPromises.push(fetch(fetchurl, {
              method: "GET",
              body: json
            }));
        }

        Promise.all(apiPromises)
        .then(responses => {
            var processedResponses = [];
            responses.map(response => response.json()
                .then(json => {
           /****THIS LINE ADDS THE SAME JSON RESPONSE MULTIPLE TIMES*****/
                    processedResponses.push(json.setlists.setlist);
                })
             )   
            console.log('processedResponses: ', processedResponses)     

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it solves the problem, but one issue is that you are logging `processedResponses` before the promises are resolved.

You can simplify your code a lot by moving the `response.json()` call:

```
apiPromises.push(
  fetch(fetchurl, {method: "GET", body: json})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => json.setlists.setlist);
);

// ...

Promise.all(apiPromises).then(processedResponses => console.log(processedResponses));
```

Comment: Thx for the reply.  I tried this and it did not solve the issue of the same json being pushed multiple times.

Comment: In that case every call either returns the same data or `json.setlists.setlist` is the same value in every response. It's impossible for the example that I provided to process a single API call multiple times.

Comment: `json.setlists.setlist` is indeed the same in every response.  However every response call is for a different url:

url
:
"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.setlist.fm/rest/0.1/artist/83b9cbe7-9857-49e2-ab8e-b57b01038103/setlists.json?page%20=%2049"

And:
url
:
"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.setlist.fm/rest/0.1/artist/83b9cbe7-9857-49e2-ab8e-b57b01038103/setlists.json?page%20=%2050"

Comment: But `json.setlists.setlist` is the value you are pulling out, ignoring any other part of the response. So if that value is the same in every response you end up with an array that contains the same value `n` times. If you want to get the whole response, don't do `.then(json => json.setlists.setlist);`.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to tell you. If you think the value of `json.setlists.setlist` should be different in every response, read the API documentation of service you are using and verify that you are sending the correct parameters. If `json.setlists.setlist` is expected to be the same but you want a different value, then don't access `json.setlists.setlist` but a different part of the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154473/discussion-between-homersheineken-and-felix-kling).